# How do I keep text within the borders of the div without clipping?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to keep text within the borders of a div table cell, but without clipping.

The problem is that the text keeps overflowing out of its cell div. Please understand that the text doesn't have words that are too long for the width of the div.

Also, when I remove the "float: left" element from the cell div, the whole div table gets messed up.

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width:302px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    word-break:break-all;
    }

.row {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:300px;
    }
```

Comment: please post your html also

Comment: Add you html code too and if possible it is good practice to include a link of your code hosted on any online code editor like "jsfiddle" etc. It will make things much easier for someone to give you quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the CSS you provided, it seems no problem. can you provide the HTML as well?

```css
 .table {
   display: table;
   width: 302px;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: center;
   word-break: break-all;
 }
 .row {
   display: table-row;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 .cell {
   float:left;
   min-height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   height: auto;
   margin-top: 0px;
   width: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure it out.